# Inconsistencies with HTML5 video in an Android WebView

Tags: android, html, video, webview

When showing an .mp4 video on an HTML5 page in an Android WebView, the video and audio are both played back properly when the file is retrieved from a remote URL.  When trying to play the same media file from within the device's "/mnt/sdcard/...." path, only the audio portion of the media file is played back.  Any thoughts on this ?  Has anyone experienced (and hopefully solved) anything similar?  Could this be a codec issue despite the fact that video is seen when retrieved over a network?  Is video returned over a network manipulated or transformed somehow before ending up in the WebView.

Comment: do you have hardware acceleration enabled in your manifest (see this example https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code worked for me, I hope it helps you,
also I think a lot of people are facing the same problem, so this is what I did to get the **HTML5 video** to run in my Applications **WebView**.

I'll walk you through the **procedure**.

I wanted to load multiple HTML pages, one after another, inside my **App's WebView**. These HTML pages contained either a **Audio followed by a Video**, or a **Video followed by a Audio**.

Here is a sample of one such HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>screen2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="css/main-v1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/screen2-v1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/jQueryTest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <audio id="audio1" src="audio/screen2_a.mp3"></audio>
        <video id="video1" src="video/mov_bbb.mp4"></video> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I created Class to act as an **interface between Android** and the **Javascript in the HTML pages**.

Here is the JavaScriptInterface class named **JsHandler.java** in my Projects **src** folder

```
package com.example.dms;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.example.dms.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class JsHandler {
    Activity activity;
    String TAG = "JsHandler";
    WebView webView;

    public JsHandler(Activity _contxt,WebView _webView) {
        activity = _contxt;
        webView = _webView;
    }

    /**
     * This function handles call from JS
     */
    @JavascriptInterface 
    public void initVideo()
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo()");
    }

    public void initAudio()
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:playAudio()");
    }

    /**
     * This function handles call from Android-Java
     */
    public void javaFnCall(String jsString) {

        final String webUrl = "javascript:diplayJavaMsg('"+jsString+"')";
        // Add this to avoid android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception unable to add window
        if(!activity.isFinishing()) 
            // loadurl on UI main thread
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl(webUrl); 
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * function shows Android-Native Alert Dialog
     */
    public void showDialog(String msg){

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();  
        alertDialog.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.app_dialog_title));
        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);  
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,activity.getString(R.string.ok_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {  
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }); 
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,activity.getString(R.string.cancel_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }); 
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

This is the code in my MainActivity, that loads the HTML page inside the WebView

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

//WebView Variables
private JsHandler _jsHandler;
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !view.hasFocus()) {
                    view.requestFocus();
                }
            return false;
        }
    });

    initWebView();   
}

private void initWebView(){

    //Tell the WebView to enable javascript execution.
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));

        //Set whether the DOM storage API is enabled.
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        //setBuiltInZoomControls = false, removes +/- controls on screen
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 8);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    _jsHandler = new JsHandler(this, myWebView);        
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(_jsHandler, "JsHandler");

    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // these settings speed up page load into the webview
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/screen2.html");

}
```

}

This is considering that your **HTML page** which is **to be loaded resides in the assets folder** of the project.

What I did is I placed the **Media files** in the **mnt/sdcard/**

For which I need to change the **src** attribute of the **audio and video** tags accordingly. Also as I mentioned earlier the JavaScriptInterface class that I created, I'll use that class to call the Audio or the Video to play from Java, instead of HTML handling it.

So, here is how the new HTML page looks like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>screen2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="css/main-v1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/screen2-v1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/jQueryTest.js"></script>

        <script>
            function playVideo()
            {
                var cV = document.getElementById("video1");
                cV.addEventListener('ended', function ()
                                                {
                                                    cV.removeEventListener('ended'); 
                                                    playAudio();
                                                }, false);
                cV.play();
            }

            function playAudio()
            {
                var cA = document.getElementById("audio1");
                cA.addEventListener('ended', function ()
                                                {
                                                    cA.removeEventListener('ended'); 
                                                    playVideo();
                                                }, false);
                cA.play();
            }
            function init(){

                JsHandler.initVideo();
            }
        </script>
        <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                init();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <audio id="audio1" src="/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.exapmle.dms/files/resources/audio/screen2_a.mp3"></audio>
            <video id="video1" src="/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.exapmle.dms/files/resources/video/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>

    </body>
</html>
```

To explain what's happening here is that, when the HTML page loads completely, I've called the **init();** method defined in the HTML page.

This method calls the **initVideo();** method defined in the **JsHandler Class**

As you can see, this **initVideo();** method gives a call to **playVideo();** method defined in the HTML page.

You may be wondering why not call the **playVideo();** method directly on **page load**,
well I've tried it and it didn't work, (atleast for me).

I hope it helps you or anyone else who's facing a similar problem in loading **HTML 5 Video** in **WebView**