# Local video refuses to play properly

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I'm having difficulties getting HTML5 video to work with the Android webview.

Everything is already set up:

- Android mini pc - MK802IIIs (Dual core)
- Android 4.1
- Hardware acceleration is enabled.
- Permissions granted for network, read/write of internal and external storage.
- WebView has a webviewclient and a chromewebviewclient.
- Javascript/plugins are enabled.
- Video's used for this example are big buck bunny in mp4 and webm formats.

**What does work:**

Loading the video into the webview from an URL that's hosted on my internal network. It gets played properly.

**What does not work:**

Loading the video from Androids storage. results in the following:
[image]
The video plays according to controls but all that is show is a black canvas with a tiny line of colored pixels.

No error messages get thrown in logcat either.
I wonder if anyone has experienced this before.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can check out the following link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533170/inconsistencies-with-html5-video-in-an-android-webview/18170001#18170001][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533170/inconsistencies-with-html5-video-in-an-android-webview/18170001#18170001

Comment: Shame that I totally missed that one, thanks a lot.

Comment: I've tried to do it through javascript interfacing but that didn't work either. Still playing the video with 1 line of pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Android doesn't like to play HTML video's straight from it's SDCard.
What I did to fix it was to use busybox and run its httpd as a small webserver which allows me to stream the video locally without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Deejdd, it would help if you can post your code, so that I'll be able to figure out what part in you code is not working

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I havn't been active on SO for a while sorry for that. In the meantime I figured it out.